# Scraping Data from Facebook Marketplace using GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from Facebook Marketplace in a legal way by using their APIs and access tokens. My first attempt is to use GraphAPI with queries in the form of

```
https://graph.facebook.com/post_id?access_token=token&fields=comments.summary(true).limit(999).filter(stream).fields(id,message,created_time,parent)
```

However using the post id from Facebook Marketplace doesn't seem to be working, giving me the error message

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '292294948474070' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "AOhjN4-go7O0hWgLpJDcWCQ"
   }
}
```

Is there another way to scrape data from Marketplace or some method of GraphAPI that I am missing? My goal for the project is to analyze the market for surfboard sales on Marketplace from this page https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/honolulu/search/?sortBy=creation_time_descend&query=surfboard&exact=false.

Comment: Marketplace posts are not available in the API

Comment: Should I try to get written consent to scrape the data manually?

Comment: @PaulM Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Avi I did not and decided not to pursue the project